# SentryOne Plan Explorer properties window

Tags: execution-plan

Does the SentryOne Plan Explorer have a properties window similar to SSMS. I see the tool tip window next to the operators in the execution plan but no properties option ?

Comment: What properties are you looking for? Most of the properties you would find buried in the panels in SSMS per operator are organized nicely for you on other tabs like top operations and plan tree.

Comment: I'm looking for Predicates and Seek Predicates. My plan has both on one of the index seeks. I see the the Seek Predicates in the Query Columns tab not the Predicate though. FYI the predicate on the tooltip is a CASE statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you right-click on the column header on any of the grids, there is an option called Column Chooser:

> [image]

This exposes a panel that lists all the columns that are available in that grid. You can drag any of these onto any location in the grid. Here is an example from Top Operations, where both `Predicate` and `Seek Predicates` are available:

> [image]

The really nice thing about the grids is that all operators are listed together. In SSMS, to compare some of the more obscure properties between two operators, you either have to flip between tooltips and/or properties panels, or take screen shots (ugh).

If you post your plan somewhere and describe which index seek you mean, I can show you how to make these properties front and center.